# Eigenvalue library for c++, recommendations, how to implement, looking for something similar to dgeev from fortran

Tags: c++, xcode, fortran, libraries, fortran95

I am new to C++, with some training using fortran95.  Trying to convert my knowledge into the new syntax but have run into a snag.

Many of my programs use modules with subroutines, and subroutines within subroutines and use of functions from a library described by NAG.com which are readily available and searchable.

I am currently looking for a c++ version of

http://www.nag.com/numeric/FL/manual/pdf/F08/f08naf.pdf

From what I have read so far, these libraries exist for c++ and I have used some simple ones thus far(like vector, cmath, math.h) but only ones that are already included in my Xcode package for my mac.

I haven't seen anybody mention one of these which my be included with my Xcode, and I am lacking in how to implement outside libraries I find.  I am interested particularly in using:

http://www.alglib.net/download.php

Thus far I have been using subrutines as void type functions and simply including them in all of my code.  But my code is becoming exceedingly cumbersome and I would like to make something similar to a fortran module to do chebyshev calculations. And I would much rather find a good library of eignevalue calculators and maybe even chebyshev calculators,  . . . which I can use.

Essentially my question is, how do I implement external libraries I find and does anybody have a recommendation for a good one?  How can I make my own code which contains a callable set of functions and then call it from within another piece of code?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, the part of the NAG library you're using in Fortran is basically LAPACK. There is a C interface to LAPACK, called LAPACKE (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lapacke.html). You can use it in a C++ program.

I didn't understand the other parts of your question.